# Symfony2 console Restricted access

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony2. When I would like to use app/console program, I get a "Restricted access" error.

Is this permission problem or what else?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it as `php app/console`. If it works, you need to `chmod +x app/console` to make it executable to be able to run it without prepending `php`.

Comment: Thanks your answer; I can run php app/console without error. I has tried your advice, but don't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I has found the error. I copied some other files ( no Symfony2 Entity files ) into Entity directory a few days ago, so I get the Restricted error when I want to run app/console doctrine:schema:update command.

thanks